# Regex for seperate to parentheses and operators in c#

Tags: c#, regex, operators, parentheses

i must use regex for part of my project. I want to seperate for AND,OR operators from given inputs. But i don't need operators which are situated in parentheses.

**Example input** : C1 OR [C2 AND C3] AND C4 OR C5 AND [C6 AND C7  OR C8 ] OR C9

**Output** : OR AND OR AND OR

**Other Example input** : C1 AND C2 AND [C3 OR C4] AND C5

**Output** : AND AND AND

Comment: So, what did you try.. if you "must" use regex, that sounds like homework

Comment: If you have deeply nested parentheses groups like `((((a AND b) OR c) AND d) OR e) AND f` you'll have a headache and tend to regex hell. So if you are able to avoid regex, consider use of [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), you can use finite state machine to track parenthesis group open/close status and recursive algorithm to parse your string into tree.

Comment: I write "must" use regex. Because i tried to split methods but it did not solve my problem. Also i tried to regex but i can not seperate which parentheses and their includes.

Comment: Do you have nested parentheses? Do you really have to use regex, or does any another algorithm that works suffice for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have nested parantheses you can do it this way:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "1 OR[C2 AND C3] AND C4 OR C5 AND[C6 AND C7 OR C8] OR C9";
            var filtered = Regex.Replace(input, "\\[.*?\\]", string.Empty);
            var result = filtered.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(element => element == "OR" || element == "AND");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That way solved my problem. Thanks..